# Android 4.0.4 - WebView - Appcache: wildcard does not work in NETWORK section

Tags: android-webview, html5-appcache

I want to clarify in manifest that AJAX-calls to web-services only get executed when online. For that I used the `NETWORK` section of the manifest:

```
NETWORK:
/WebServices/*
```

But this causes calls of the error-callback of the JQuery function `$.getJSON` at every request even when online.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the WebView of Android doesn't like the wilcard `*`. Then when adding all URLs called by AJAX functions it works like expected:

```
NETWORK:
/WebServices/Typen
/WebServices/Hersteller
...
```

But that's endless work when developing an webapp. So I decided to put all the functions with AJAX-requests in a separate file. This file now gets an entry in the `FALLBACK` section of the manifest:

```
FALLBACK:
js/webServices.js js/ajaxStub.js
```

Every function contained in `webServices.js` is implemented again in the fallback file `ajaxStub.js` while returning default-values or store data to submit to the server.